# Mass-assignment warning not shown when running rake tasks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, warnings, mass-assignment

I have a seed file with a couple of lines like the following:

```
action_type = ActionType.find_or_create_by_name(:name => "register")
```

Now, when I execute rake db:seed, although the command finishes without mentioning any warnings, no record is created in the database.

It was only when executing the above line in the rails console, that it complained with a "WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: name" message.

Any idea how I can make rake db:seed show this type of warning?

BTW just adding the name to the attr_accessible list solves the issue:

```
class ActionType < Base
  attr_accessible :name

  validates :name, :presence => true
end
```